# Gradle: dependencies compatibility

Tags: java, gradle, compatibility

How can I ensure with gradle, that all my dependencies are compatible with Java version I use in my project?
Eg. I compile my project with JDK 1.6 and one of my dependencies is compiled with JDK 1.8. Will it work? 
What other incompatibilities may I encounter (especially during dependency version updates) and how do I deal with them?

Comment: "*I compile my project with JDK 1.6*" - That stuff is over 10 years old. Is there a specific reason you use JDK 1.6? --- "*[...] one of my dependencies is compiled with JDK 1.8. Will it work?*" - Most probably not.

Comment: Reading breaking changes in release notes

Comment: Do you have a real issue to address here or just wondering?

Comment: @Turing85 Unfortunately, I am developing a corporate application which is still running on JDK 1.6. How do I ensure dependency compatibility?

Comment: @zee I have to ensure somehow (preferably automatically) that the dependencies will be compatible with the application compiled with JDK 1.6.